# How do I create a list of the selected options from a dropdwon

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, html-select

I am trying to loop through a multiple select dropdown list and add all of the selected options to a comma separated list.

My dropdown code is:

```
<select name="testnameID" id="testnameID" multiple>
  <option value="1">Test number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test number 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test number 5</option>
<select>
```

In my  tag I am using the following, but think it can be simplified or improved:

```
var testnameID = $('#testnameID').val();
var testnameText;            
Array.from(document.querySelector("#testnameID").options).forEach(function(option_element) {
            let option_text = option_element.text;
            let is_option_selected = option_element.selected;

            if (is_option_selected===true){
                testnameText = testnameText + option_text +", ";
                console.log("TestnameText: "+testnameText);
                console.log("\n\r");
            }
            
        });
```

I need to generate a variable, testnameText, which if the first three items were selected, would return a value of "Test number 1, Test number 2, Test number 3"

I'm getting myself in a muddle!

Comment: Since you are using a multi-select, the .val() should return all selected values anyway, should it not? It would on sending a form, anyway. If it returns an array you could just do `Array.join(',')`. But honestly in my opinion, multi-selects are horribly user unfriendly so I'd recommend using checkboxes anyway... Other than that, your code seems fine to me. -- The answer of @mamun is a good improvement, though.

Comment: I am using the val() to get the values. That's working, but I need to create a list of the text options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, jquery's [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) can help. So getting selected options is pretty simple:

```js
$('#testnameID :selected').each(function (index, el) {
    console.log("TestnameText: " + $(el).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="testnameID" id="testnameID" multiple>
    <option value="1" selected>Test number 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Test number 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Test number 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test number 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test number 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great thanks - I used this to get it working! Awesome.

Comment: @petworthnick, My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the selected options like the following way:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#testnameID option:checked")).forEach(function(option_element) {
  let option_text = option_element.text;

  var testnameText = option_text +", ";
  console.log("TestnameText: "+testnameText);
  console.log("\n\r");
});
```

```html
<select name="testnameID" id="testnameID" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>Test number 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Test number 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Test number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test number 5</option>
<select>
```

You can also try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Arrow function expressions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is more shorter.

The following example creates an array of the selected options:

```js
var checkedOptions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#testnameID option:checked"));
var res = checkedOptions.map(option_element => ("TestnameText: "+option_element.text));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<select name="testnameID" id="testnameID" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>Test number 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Test number 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Test number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test number 5</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) contains all the selected options of a select element. You can use it like this:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // Option texts as an array
  const texts = Array.from(e.target.selectedOptions).map(({text}) => text);
  // Option texts as a comma-separated string
  const textsStr = texts.join(', ');
  console.log(texts);
  console.log(textsStr);
});
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">Test number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test number 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test number 5</option>
</select>
```

This works outside of the event too, just refer the select element directly instead of `e.target`.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go and see if I can get it working.